# How to support c/c++ standard library(newlib) on custom riscv platform?

Tags: c++, stl, g++, riscv, linker-scripts

I wrote a riscv emulator that loads riscv .elf files compiled with riscv64 unknown elf toolchain compiled with newlib support and c++ support. It is able to run programs that don't use any c/c++ stl functions. However I would like to be able to use stl functions like printf, cout, vector and malloc and stuff.

I however am unsure how to properly do this. Removing -nostdlib from my g++/gcc command works and allows me to compile programs that make use of stl features, however they don't work properly. Mild usage seems to be mostly ok, but heavier usage causes it to start trashing program storage(.text at 0, usage of certain stl features causes 0 writes to address 0x00000004 and up). My guess is that's happening because I'm missing things in my init function like initializing constructors, providing things heap and such.

Now, I know I probably need those(and probably more things), but I have no idea how to add those. So I'd like some help.
This is my current linker script:

```
ENTRY(riscvcoreinitfunction);

MEMORY
{
    ram   (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x003E8000
}

STACK_SIZE = 0xFFFF;

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        KEEP(*(.vector*))
        *(.text*)
    } > ram

    .bss (NOLOAD) :
    {
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
    } > ram

    .data :
    {
        *(.data*);
    } > ram

    .stack (NOLOAD) :
    {
        . = ALIGN(8);
        . = . + STACK_SIZE;
        . = ALIGN(8);
    } > ram

    __global_pointer$ =. + 0x10000;
}
```

And my current init function:

```
extern "C"
{
    void riscvcoreinitfunction()
    {
        asm volatile
        ("   .option push               \t\n\
                 .option norelax            \t\n\
                 1:auipc gp, %pcrel_hi(__global_pointer$) \t\n\
                 addi  gp, gp, %pcrel_lo(1b) \t\n\
                .option pop                 \t\n\
        ");
        asm volatile("" ::: "memory");
        main();
    }
}
```

And this is what I use to call g++:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/riscv64-unknown-elf-g++ -nostartfiles -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 -T linkerscript.ld -o bin.elf
```

I found a tutorial online for implementing newlib in my platform, but it doesn't really work for me and lacks details like what variables I need in my linkerscript. Also in the tutorial things like sbrk are undefined, where in my program they already have an implementation somehow for some reason.(So how do I replace them if needed?)
Could anyone assist me in adding support for all the basic c/c++ features required and stl features?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the toolchain provide you with all the init functions?

Comment: @perencia It does provide one init function(_init irc), but that would prevent me from adding my own initialization code. Are there more than _init?

Comment: Not being any expert, I think you shouldn't provide any. That's the job of the toolchain. Maybe your emulator is not acting in the way the toolchain expects.

Comment: Well, the thing is I'm not really emulating a platform, I'm creating a new one. So I think some custom init functions will be needed. And even if I could use existing init functions if they exist, I'd still need to know which parameter to add to my linkerscript.

Comment: I don't understand, shouldn't your new platform comply with the riscv? Isn't riscv the platform?

Comment: @perencia Well, riscv is the isa. The platform is what has ram, peripherals and such. The riscv isa doesn't specify those(and thus also not where they are and how to use them). So because my ram configuration or perhipherals could be different I have to set it up correctly, and I think I might be missing some things in my linkerscript required for full c++ and stl.

Comment: I was thinking, don't you need an OS to use newlib? I mean, for doing cout i.e. Are you running any OS on your platform?

Comment: @perencia No it isn't required if I provide my own function replacement for the calls required by e.g. cout and printf. E.g. _write for writing to console I believe.